# Webstorm console infos source?

Tags: node.js, console, webstorm

While playing with NodeJS in Webstorm I came to a point where 'suddenly' this output appeared. Until now I didn't have all the 'time .. express:router .. ' lines:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 9.0.1\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --debug-brk=49723 --nolazy srv.js
debugger listening on port 49723
Tue, 06 Jan 2015 11:15:06 GMT express:router:route new *
Express server listening  0.0.0.0:80
Tue, 06 Jan 2015 11:15:06 GMT express:router:layer new *
Tue, 06 Jan 2015 11:15:06 GMT express:router:route get *
Tue, 06 Jan 2015 11:15:06 GMT express:router:layer new /
Tue, 06 Jan 2015 11:15:06 GMT express:application compile etag weak
Tue, 06 Jan 2015 11:15:06 GMT express:application compile query parser extended
Tue, 06 Jan 2015 11:15:06 GMT express:application compile trust proxy false
Tue, 06 Jan 2015 11:15:06 GMT express:application booting in development mode
Tue, 06 Jan 2015 11:15:06 GMT express:router use / query
Tue, 06 Jan 2015 11:15:06 GMT express:router:layer new /
Tue, 06 Jan 2015 11:15:06 GMT express:router use / expressInit
```

I try to understand which setting or function is responsible for this. My simple code:

```
'use strict';

var appEnv = 'development'; //'production'
var appPort = 80;

var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var resource = require('express-resource'); 
var session = require('express-session');

// here the mentioned output appears first during step-by-step debugging:
var appRouter = require('./routes/index');
var user = require('./routes/user');
...
```

I guess it's not a Node then more a Webstorm question, right? Probably there is a setting for this ... which I didn't find. Maybe there is a key combination I hit by mistake?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These messages are logged by Express when running in debug mode. See http://expressjs.com/guide/debugging.html

Comment: Thanks to lena. I was a bit stupid: I did run "normal" mode in Webstorm, I didn't find a "Debug the project" option in Webstorm Settings, and I didn't see a "debug" key word in my code .. but there is a DEBUG Windows environment variable (which was set by a batch).. rrr!

Answer (score 1):

It's a Webstorm Debugger console info. U might have clicked on "debug the project" option in your IDE.